# Still having simple javascript trouble

Tags: javascript, html

```
if (document.getElementById) {

function alterImg() {
    document.body.getElementById('sendimg').src="url('images/tridown.png')";
}

}
```

and then the html:

```
<div id="sendbutton">
<img id="sendimg" src="images/tri.png" onclick="alterImg()" />
</div>
```

i tried using a this keyword reference too, to no avail.

Comment: Why is `url('images/tridown.png')` in quotes?

Comment: @pdizz: I don't think it's meant to be an invokation of a `url()` function, just another error.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems here:

1. the src attribute does not need to be wrapped around url()
2. Use **document.getElementById** instead of **document.body.getElementById**

   function alterImg() {
       document.getElementById('sendimg').src = "images/tridown.png";
   }

Answer (score 2):

Three problems with your code:

- Your using document *.body* .getElementById. "`getElementById`" is a method of the `document`, not the body element.
- You're mixing css with html. In html, you assign a url to the `src` attribute of an image. In css, you use `url(...)` to reference an image, e.g. for backgrounds.
- You're using a function declaration in an if statement. Please note that this does declare the function in the current scope (I assume global), regardless whether the if-block gets executed or not. If you want to define the function only when `document.getElementById` is available, you will need to use

```
if (document.getElementById) {
    var alterImg = function () {
        document.getElementById('sendimg').src="images/tridown.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually if-blocks don't create scope so alterImg will still be available outside the block :)

Comment: @shingokko: It's not only that the declaration is escaping the statement block, but also that a declaration isn't technically allowed to be there according to the spec. Implementations do allow it (in violation), but strict mode absolutely prohibits it.

Comment: @Bergi what you wrote makes perfect sense. sorry didn't read it carefully at first.

Answer (score 1):

document.**body**.getElementById

Comment: that's just a browser test, it shouldn't be the problem. Ive had code work in that if structure before.

Comment: There is no `getElementById` on `document.body`.

Answer (score 0):

remove the url('') statement from .src="url('images/tridown.png')"

The below worked for me:

```
<div id="sendbutton">
<img id="sendimg" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" onclick="alterImg()" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById) {

function alterImg() {
    document.body.getElementById('sendimg').src="http://placehold.it/128x128";
}

}

</script>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementById` method is only defined on the `document` object, not on `document.body`. Also, the `src` property is not a CSS property, so you can't use `url(...)` as value. You should simply write:

```
document.getElementById('sendimg').src = images/tridown.png";
```

For a more complete description of the `HTMLImageElement`, check out the [Mozilla Developer Network](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement).